# Azure Alert on a Resource (Azure Logic App) is being triggered only once

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts, azure-metrics-advisor

I have an Azure Logic App running every 3 minutes. I'm intentionally failing the Logic App every time, to test the Alert functionality.

The status of the alert created is **Enabled**.

```
The condition is Whenever the count of runs failed is greater than or equal to 1
Threshold: Static
Operator: Greater than or equal to
Aggregation Type: Count
Threshold value: 1
Unit: Count
Aggregation granularity (Period): 1 minute
Frequency of evaluation: Every 1 minute
```

Although the Logic App is running every 3 minutes and failing, in the past 1.5 hours, I have just received just a single mail **Your Azure Monitor alert was triggered**. I've even changed the **Change alert state** blade from the mail to **Closed**.

The Alert is not getting triggered after the 1st mail.

Any help is going to be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview).
[image]

The document above is for VM, but it's same to our case. When your logic app failed and trigger the alert, you need to wait for a few minutes, it will send another email to notify you the azure monitor alert was resolved. After that, the next alert can be triggered and send you alert email normally.